Для чего нужен super() в ООП python?
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name  # имя человека

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    def display_info(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.__name}")


class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, company):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.company = company

    def display_info(self):
        super().display_info()
        print(f"Company: {self.company}")

    def work(self):
        print(f"{self.name} works")


tom = Employee("Tom", "Microsoft")
tom.display_info()  # Name: Tom
# Company: Microsoft

Пример взял с сайта метанит. Не понимаю для чего нужен super(), почему банально там нельзя также прописать self.name = name?

Если ваша задача — сделать self.name видимым для всех подряд, то конечно можно. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что задача автора на метаните — наоборот спрятать name от посторонних

Ну хорошо одно поле. А если будет 20 таких полей у родителя - тоже будете все поля дублировать в наследнике? А уверены, что нигде не ошибётесь и назовёте все поля точно так же? В общем, надёжнее отдать работу уже написанному коду, чем дублировать его. Вероятность ошибок повышается при дублировании кода.

Задача ООП в распределении обязанностей между классами, что если метод __init__ класса Person будет, например, как-нибудь ещё обрабатывать аргумент name и допустим будет применять к нему метод str.title(), предлагаете в классе Employee полностью копировать эту логику и получить дублирование кода? Представьте только если в Person.__init__() будет страшная логика на 100+ строчек. Это если еще и не учитывать что в классе Person переопределено получение значения атрибута name

@CrazyElf тут стоит отметить, что self.name это вообще read-only property и присваивание туда не заработает (мне стоило упомянуть это в первом комментарии, но чёт затупил)
